# Sorting Letter Grade with Query Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a live dashboard using a query with this formula

```
=QUERY('Calibration Worksheet'!A4:U,"SELECT S, COUNT (S) WHERE S IS NOT NULL GROUP BY S  PIVOT H")
```

and it shows this table

| Department | Another header | A | A+ | B | B+ | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | row | 7 | 3 | 3 | 18 | 1 |
| Accounting | row | 4 | 2 | 13 | 11 |  |

Can I make the letter grade become this {A+, A, B+, B, C} with query formula? and how to make the blank space become 0?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it with personal data removed), so that the volunteer contributors here have actual data and a place to test formulas. There are ways to work this out; but without seeing your spreadsheet, international locale, data, data types, layout, etc., it would be difficult to make any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This Formula. in `I1`

```
=ArrayFormula(if(QUERY({ A1:B,D1:D,C1:C,F1:F,E1:E,G1:G}, "Select * Where Col1 is not null")<>"",QUERY({ A1:B,D1:D,C1:C,F1:F,E1:E,G1:G}, "Select * Where Col1 is not null"),0))
```

[image]